# Adding continual data to a users ID?

Tags: mysql

I'm very new to using SQL, and I'm trying to figure out a way to store a bunch of data that will continually get updated. I know comcating all the data to the end of the current data is a HUGE nono, it takes the relational of of SQL.

I only have two columns, one is UID, and the other SID. The UID is a users ID, and the SID is their account. If they create another account, they will have the same UID. I want to add the SID to their UID, but not add it again if both of the columns are duplicates.

I'm guessing I have to just have a bunch of the same UID's in the DB, or is there a different way I can go about this?

Example:

What I would like:

```
|-----UID-----|--SID--|
|aa721910fe51 |6811112, 1111114|
|h678910fe761 |4444112|
```

What I think is the proper way, but not sure how to go about it?

```
|-----UID-----|--SID--|
|aa721910fe51 |6811112|
|aa721910fe51 |1111114|
|h678910fe761 |4444112|
```

If I do something like below, It only checks the UID if there is a duplicate, and ignores it. I would like to check the UID, if it exists, check and see if the SID exists, if it doesn't, add it.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO users (UID, SID) VALUES ('aa721910fe51', '6811112')
```

Sorry if this is noobie stuff, i search and I couldn't fine anything.

Comment: Another nono: storiing values in comma separated lists. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad

Comment: Assuming you store the data in the style of the second table in your question, you can just create a unique index over the `UID` and `SID` columns together e.g. `ALTER TABLE yourtable ADD UNIQUE INDEX (UID, SID)`

Comment: Instead of Unique, better option would to be to create a Primary Index on them